# Jquery Hide and Show and switch image with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

i create jquery for image upload preview, i want function for my button remove that will switch back to the default image (placeholder) when it get click.the condition for remove is when the button remove get click it will check  if image upload preview is not equal my placeholder then it will switch back to the placeholder. from here it work well, but because i have two image upload previews, when i click the button remove it switch both of image upload preview to the default image (placeholder). How can i make that spesific so it only change the image upload preview that i want to remove.

And the second question is how to hide the image footer when the image preview still at default image (placeholder) and it will show up after i choose my upload image

```
  <div class="image-upload">
        <label for="inputFile1">
            <img id="image_upload_preview1" class="main-image"src="img/550.png"/>
               <div class="img-footer">
                  <div class="remove-do">
                    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-alert btn-remove default" style="padding: 0px 5px;" aria-label="Left Align">
                        <i class="fa fa-times" title="Delete" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white;"></i>
                        <span class="sr-only">Delete</span>
                    </button>
                    <p style="display: inline-block;">remove</p>
        </div>
     </div>
    </label>
    <input id="inputFile1" type="file"/>
        </div>

    <div class="image-upload">
        <label for="inputFile2">
            <img id="image_upload_preview2" class="sub-image" src="img/550.png"/>
                <div class="img-footer" style=" left: 15px; right: 15px;">
                    <div class="remove-do">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-alert btn-remove default" style="padding: 0px 5px;" aria-label="Left Align">
                            <i class="fa fa-times" title="Delete" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white;"></i>
                            <span class="sr-only">Delete</span>
                        </button>
                        <p style="display: inline-block;">remove</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </label>
            <input id="inputFile2" type="file"/>
        </div>


    ---image preview---
                // 1    
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#image_upload_preview1').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }


        }
        // /1

        // 2
          function readURLs(input) {
           if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#image_upload_preview2').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }


        }
        // /2
        $("#inputFile1").change(function () {
            readURL(this);
        });
        $("#inputFile2").change(function () {
            readURLs(this);
        });
    --image preview end--

    --function for remove and hide/show image footer--

     $(document).ready(function() { 
                var src = $(".image-upload").attr('src');

                if(src=="img/550.png")
                    $('.img-footer').hide();
                 else
                   $('.img-footer').show();

               $('.default').click(function(){
                 var src = $(this).closest(".image-upload").find('img').attr('src')[0];

                 if(src!="img/550.png")
                   $(".image-upload img").attr('src',"img/550.png");
               });

            });

           --end function for remove and hide/show image footer--
```

here the link for my example code. https://jsfiddle.net/bLkzc1vc/

Comment: when i click remove (as it is), the explorer window just opens again? Is that the problem? I don't understand the 2nd question. What image footer? Please clarify

Comment: click the red strip, i use font awesome but didnt plugin to jsfiddle. image footer is the black box that contain  button remove.

Comment: its pretty easy to include fa in fiddles. Just put the link into external resources. Update your fiddle.

Comment: okay i finish plug the fontawesome, can u help me mamm pleasee

Comment: i don't see a link to an updated fiddle? the link changes when you update!

Comment: sorry wrong url, here: https://jsfiddle.net/bLkzc1vc/1/